# Repeat elements for unequal size objects in an R list

Tags: r, lapply

In R, I have a list comprised of objects with an unequal number of elements. For example,

```
l <- list(a=c(1,2), b=3, c=4)
```

I have figured out how to find the maximum length of any object:

```
lmax <- max(unlist(lapply(l,length)))
```

And also how to identify which objects are not the longest:

```
notlongest <- unlist(lapply(l,length)) != max(unlist(lapply(l,length)))
```

What I need to do now: for those objects in the list that are `notlongest`, repeat their elements the number of times of `lmax` and get a new list. That is, for objects b and c, repeat their elements twice so I get a new list that looks something that this:

```
newl <- list(a=c(1,2), b=c(3,3), c=c(4,4))
```

I'm sure there is an easy answer with the `lapply` function but I can't figure it out. Apologies if this question has been asked before. Thank you!

Comment: Some nitpicking, you can simplify your `unlist(lapply())` combos by using `sapply`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lmax <- max(sapply(l,length))
ll <- lapply(l, function(x) c(x, rep(x, lmax-length(x)) )  )
ll
$a
[1] 1 2

$b
[1] 3 3

$c
[1] 4 4
```

From `R 3.2.0`, `lengths(l)` can be used in place of `sapply(l,length)`

```
lmax <- max(lengths(l))
```

Comment: More direct approach, I was too lazy to think about it +1

Comment: Just happened to think, would this work for a situation where the lesser lists don't have a singular element?

Comment: Not that my way addresses that.

Comment: I suppose one could use x[1] instead of x and just pad with the first element in the vector.

Comment: Yeah or throwing a `[1:lmax]` after `c(x, rep(x, lmax-length(x)))` does the trick.  In any even this is the better approach.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is that I can think of is to use R's recycling rule and `data.frame` to group the lists into a list of equal length lists:

```
dat <- do.call('data.frame', l)
```

You can operate directly out of that structure now but if you want to create separate lists again you use `sapply` to break it back apart into separate lists:

```
sapply(dat, list)
```